# Configuring log4j for hibernate

Tags: hibernate, logging, log4j

Hi i'm writing a gwt project in eclipse.

I've trouble configuring log4j in hibernate to show the SQL parameters even in Eclipse console. After following the guide:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/

i can't see no differences at all , the SQL paramater are still question mark and even the log file is not created . How can i configure the log correctly?

My hibernate version is 3.7.0.
I've added thoose jars to my buildpath:
-slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
-slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
-slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar

i've created the **log4j.properties** in the classpath of my project:

```
    # Direct log messages to a log file
      log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
      log4j.appender.file.File=server_log.log
      log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
      log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
      log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
      log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

     # Direct log messages to stdout
     log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
      log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
      log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
      log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

       # Root logger option
       log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

       # Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
       log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

       # Log all JDBC parameters
       log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As per your log4j.properties file i can see you are missing one key attribute

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

Your log4j.properties file should look like this

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss, SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger = info, stdout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate = info

#following parameters will be used to log the sql parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

Please have look on this post which will help you to set up the log4j.properties file correctly : http://techpost360.blogspot.in/2016/10/hibernate-show-sql-with-parameter-values.html